# reCaptcha widgetId 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I want to get response Google reCaptcha widget when I submit my form and have some input errors or form is sent. I'm using multiple widgets on the same page so I render these widgets explicitly.

My code :

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.state.captchaWidget = grecaptcha.render( 'captcha-register', {
            'sitekey' : 'my_site_key'
        });
    }
}
addUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let response = grecaptcha.getResponse(this.state.captchaWidget );
```

Always this.state.captchaWidget return 0

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid ReCAPTCHA client id: 0
```

Comment: There are two _function_ and one } missing

Comment: See this answer. Take note of the required `PubSub` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274985/recaptcha-2-0-how-to-display-only-after-n-failed-attempts-throttling/30466061#30466061